# How to change language list order in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to programmatically change the order of the languages in "Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language" in Windows 8.

I.e. do the same as "Move Up" and "Move Down" buttons do on the language dialog. Which API function can be used for this task? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use the [`EnumSystemLocalesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317829(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SetLocalInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049(v=vs.85).aspx) function for that. Don't forget to broadcast the [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) to notify all other applications of the change.

Regions and languages are added under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile`, the order is determined by the multi-string value `Language`.

The order of keyboard layouts is under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd like a cleaner approach, I mean there must be an API for it.

Comment: Thank you for your update, I've tried all of the possible parameters for SetLocalInfo and none of them works with the language list. There is one that sets the default language, but my task is change the list order instead. Any other ideas? Thanks